# java playframework read json from request body

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to read a json from a request body.

my in body I have:

```
DefaultRequestBody(None,None,None,None,None,Some(MultipartFormData(Map(json -> List({"a":"s","b":"sd"})),List(),List(),List())))
```

Now I want to access the List ... what would be the best way in this case?

I have tried this:

```
 JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    if(json == null) {
        System.out.println("NULL");
        return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
    } else {
        String name = json.findPath("name").toString();
        if(name == null) {
            return badRequest("Missing parameter [name]");
        } else {
            return ok("Hello " + name);
        }
    }
```

but json is always null

thanks

Comment: How your GENERATE json looks like?

Comment: try to print `request().body()` first, see what's inside that, I guess it will clear the picture.

Comment: Already done this its the Line mentioned above

Comment: any idea how to access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this workes for me

```
Http.RequestBody body = request().body();
JsonNode json = body.asJson();

System.out.println(json);
```